# Thymeleaf ignores "\n" in String returned from method

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf

In my HTML I'm using paragraph that gets content by calling method via thymeleaf:

```
<p data-th-text="${fund.formatDescription()}"></p>
```

Method:

```
private String description;

public String formatDescription() {  
    return description.replace(";", " \n ");
}
```

I want my description to have end lines in palce of every semicolon. So that's why I added `\n`. But thymeleaf ingores new lines and returns continuous text. I tried adding `<br/>` but it ends up not interpreted as html. What should I add in place of semicolon to force new line in the description?

Comment: `</br>` is invalid. the correct syntax is `<br/>` the / of self-closing tags is always at the end.

Comment: @litelite You're right but had in my code `<br/>` it's just a typo in the question.

Comment: See [Thymeleaf + Spring : How to keep line break?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394419/thymeleaf-spring-how-to-keep-line-break).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Html ignores newlines (this isn't thymeleaf's fault).  You can either:

- Put the description into `<pre></pre>` tags (or use the css `white-space` property on the `<p>` element).
- Instead of replacing `;` with `\n`, replace it with `<br />` and use `th:utext` instead of `data-th-text`.  (This means that html will be unescaped, so you better make sure users can't put other html into the description field or you open yourself up to html attacks).

Comment: Still the same result, I can see on website `<br/>` as normal text. I've tried with `data-th-utext` but still tags are not interpreted as HTML.

Comment: @MichaelDz -- I verified this works before posting my answer, and you can see the documentation for utext [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#more-on-texts-and-variables)... can you verify your replace?  What does the html look like when you view-source?

Comment: That's how HTML source looks like `<p>text <br/> text <br/> text</p>, I've used `data-th-utext` in my paragraph, `<pre>` tag doesn't help either.

Comment: @MichaelDz --  think you've got something else going on. It would look like `<p>test &lt;br /&gt; test &lt;br /&gt; final</p>` if utext were not working.

Comment: for some reason `data-th-utext` is not working with HTML tags. But instead I've replaced it with `th:utext` and now it is working fine! Thank you  for help, add this to your answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: " with \n, replace it with <br /> and use th:utext instead of data-th-text", works perfectly  for me, thank you so much for both of you. Cheers !!!

Answer (score 1):

I made a Thymeleaf dialect that makes it easy to keep the line breaks, if the css `white-space` property isn't an option.
It also bring support for BBCode if you want it.
You can either import it as a dependency (it's very light) or just use it as inspiration to make your own.
Check it out here :
https://github.com/oxayotl/meikik-project