# Displaying pretty printed JSON from variable with Java Spring boot Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to pass a pretty printed JSON as a variable and have it display on an HTML page.
in my .java file:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/page1")
public String callback(Model model){
    String fruits = "{\n" +
                    "    \"fruit\": \"Apple\",\n" +
                    "    \"size\": \"Large\",\n" +
                    "    \"color\": \"Red\"\n" +
                    "}";
    JSONObject json_fruit = new JSONObject(fruits);
    System.out.println(json_fruit.toString(4));
    model.addAttribute("result", json_fruit.toString(4));
    return "page1";
```

in my page1.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Page1</title>
</head>
<body>
<p th:text="'JSON: ' + ${result}"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

when I System.out.println(), I get my json data formatted like this:

```
{
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Red",
    "fruit": "Apple"
}
```

but on my html page:

```
JSON: { "size": "Large", "color": "Red", "fruit": "Apple" }
```

Is it possible to keep the newline characters in the HTML? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use:

```
<p th:text="'JSON: ' + ${result}"  style="white-space: pre"></p>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still getting the same results in the HTML page with this

Comment: I used your original answer to find that `style="white-space: pre"`  preserves the white space and is exactly what I was looking for. The line I ended up using was `<p th:text="'JSON: ' + ${result}"  style="white-space: pre"></p>` . Thank you!