# Keep line breaks in Spring + Thymeleaf 3.0.12+

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-el

I know there's [already a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30394419/thymeleaf-spring-how-to-keep-line-break) on converting line breaks to <br> tags in Thymeleaf, but the "`#strings.replace`" solution from there, relies on getting the `line.separator` system property to make it platform neutral.  Since Thymeleaf 3.0.12 this is now broken (see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/809)) when used with `th:utext`.  Is there a recommended replacement for this, other than just using "\n"?  For reference, the current line (which we use all over our codebase) looks something like this:

```
<div th:utext="*{#strings.replace(#strings.escapeXml(fieldName),T(java.lang.System).getProperty('line.separator'),'&lt;br&gt;')}">
```

Comment: In the same thread, you have mentioned, there is the best solution (from my point of view), which unfortunately doesn't mark as the answer, is to use escaped text `th:text` with `style="white-space: pre-wrap"`. In the end, you'll get safe and formatted content. This doesn't answer your Thymeleaf question but just think about it.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I just went with `'&#10;'` instead of `line.separator`

Answer (score 1):

I made a Thymeleaf dialect that makes it easy to keep the line breaks, if the css white-space property isn't an option. It also bring support for BBCode if you want it. You can either import it as a dependency (it's very light) or just use it as inspiration to make your own. Check it out here : https://github.com/oxayotl/meikik-project